# get user mentions from Discord.py 2.0 interactions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, interaction

Using discord.py 2.0's new slash commands, how do I get mentions from discord.Interaction?

```
tree = discord.app_commands.CommandTree(client)


@tree.command(name="test", description="test")
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: str):
# ...
```

I am able to parse through the `message` param for user id's. But I was wondering if there is an easier way to maybe get a list of mentions instead of having to parse through it. If I try to print interaction.message I get None in return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to get the mentions trough the library, like [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20mentions#discord.Message.mentions), in interactions. But you can do it in an easier way instead of manually iterating through it.

Use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) to do it, like that:

```py
import re

@tree.command(name="test", description="test")
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: str):
    guild = interaction.guild

    # get the member IDs in the string
    matches = re.findall(r"<@!?([0-9]{15,20})>", message) # returns list of strings

    # create list of discord.Member
    members = [guild.get_member(int(match)) for match in matches]

    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Mentioned members: {', '.join(str(member) for member in members)}")
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

#### Edit

It exists something called `Transformer` which allows this, but in my opinion it's unnecessarily complicated for your problem. But in case you want to use it:

**Docs:** https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.Transformer 
**Example:** https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/transformers.py